# Angular MatTableDataSource is not providing data to dataSource

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a mat table and fetch the data from an API . so my service code look like this

```
     getAll(){
       return this.http.get<Apps[]>(this.ROOT_URL + 'testcases/');
      }

    getTCbyAppName(appName: any){
        return this.http.get<Apps[]>(this.ROOT_URL + 'testcases/get/'+ appName)
     }
```

and my ts file

```
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Apps>();
    displayedColumns = ['App Name', 'noOfTCs']

    fetchTableData(event: any) {
          console.log("Selected App: " + event);
          this.selected = event;
          this.tableVisibility = "visible";
   if (event == "all") {
          this.testcaseService.getAll().subscribe(result => {
          this.dataSource.data = result as Apps[];
        })
   } else {
        this.testcaseService.getTCbyAppName(event).subscribe(result => {
        this.dataSource.data = result as Apps[];
       })
   }

   }
```

html file

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" [style.visibility]="tableVisibility">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="App Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> App Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let apps"> {{apps.appName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="noOfTCs">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Testcases Count </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let apps"> {{apps.noOfTCs}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

the output only shows the column names . the api works perfectly fine and i am not sure why does this matTableDataSource is not working

note : i am using Angular 7

Answer (score 0):

When you add or remove data to datasource, make sure to render the table so the angular material will display a new data from the datasource that have been renewed.

First thing first, get a reference to the table using the ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
```

And then put this code once you had an adding or deleting operation, for example

```
this.dataSource.data = result as Apps[];
this.table.renderRows();
```

For more detail information: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I have modified the code as per your suggestion . It didnt work